# I need to animate color changes in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need the color to change sequentially. Let's say from gray to Red, then from red to green...and so on.

so far i got this:

```xml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="BlinkingStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnimationMode}" Value="BlinkingOn">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Lime" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="0:0:5" />
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" From="Lime" To="Red" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="0:0:5" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="StopFlashingStoryboard">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="LightGray" Duration="0:0:2" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <Button Command="{Binding ItemSelectedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource BlinkingStyle}">
        </Button>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

The color behavior seems to run in parallel. The color mix together upon running. I need the color to change to `Lime` over 5 secs then from `Lime` to `Red` over next 5secs then to `LightGray` for 2secs.

Comment: I think you need to use [ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-animate-color-by-using-key-frames) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the color to change to Lime over 5 secs then from Lime to Red over next 5secs then to LightGray for 2secs.

You could use a `ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames` like this:

```
<Style x:Key="BlinkingStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnimationMode}" Value="BlinkingOn">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                            <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="Lime" KeyTime="0:0:5"/>
                            <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="Red" KeyTime="0:0:10"/>
                            <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="LightGray" KeyTime="0:0:12"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks! just what i needed. btw can i ask what is the use of exit action? I still don't understand what it mean.